# Using regular expression to maintain part of information on column

Tags: regex, unix, multiple-columns, trim, cut

Good morning, I have a file looking like this:

```
file.txt

G05829  H05037  A   A*02:01:01  A*11:01:01
G05829  H05037  DRA DRA*01:01:01    DRA*01:02:02
G05829  H05037  DPB1    DPB1*04:01:01   DPB1*04:02:01
G05829  H05037  DRB3    DRB3*01:01:02   DRB3*01:01:02
G05829  H05037  B   B*08:01 B*44:02
G05829  H05037  DRB1    DRB1*03:01:01   DRB1*04:01:01
G15526  H12517  B   B*07:02 B*35:01
G15526  H12517  DRB5    DRB5*01:01:01   DRB5*01:01:01
G15526  H12517  DRA DRA*01:02:03    DRA*01:02:03
```

I need to have columns 4 and 5 in the format

```
A*01:01  A*01:01
DRA*01:01 DRA*01:01
(...)
```

So, the first letters that identify the locus, star, 2 digits, column and 2 two digits.

My problem is that not eery columns have the same length. Some will have more detailed and will have 2 or 3 colons (e.g. DPB1*01:02:02 or DQB1*49:34:01:03)while other will have only one colon (the intended output, e.g. DPA*01:01).

I have tried some different approaches but I am only able to crop from the end ( what does no work because they have different lengths), crop from the beginning (Alsop dos not work because the first identifier can be 1 letter or 3 letters and number (e.g. identifier can be 'A' or 'DPB1'). I was trying with sed, by I end up replacing all the colons. My attempts:

```
sed 's/\:[0-9][0-9]//g' file.txt
```

This crops all the colon + digits WRONG

```
sed 's/\:[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\t/\t/g' file.txt
```

This crops only the second column and does not account for differences on length in each column.

I need something that will:

recognises identifier (A,B,C,DPA1,DQB1), the star (*), the numbers after the start (01,02,13 (..)), first colon (:) and following digits before the next column (01,02,03 ...)

so, the desired output is something like this:

```
niceoutput.txt

G05829  H05037  A   A*02:01 A*11:01
G05829  H05037  DRA DRA*01:01   DRA*01:02
G05829  H05037  DPB1    DPB1*04:01  DPB1*04:02
G05829  H05037  DRB3    DRB3*01:01  DRB3*01:01
G05829  H05037  DRB1    DRB1*03:01  DRB1*04:01
G05829  H05037  B   B*08:01 B*44:02
G15526  H12517  B   B*07:02 B*35:01
G15526  H12517  DRB5    DRB5*01:01  DRB5*01:01
G15526  H12517  DRA DRA*01:02   DRA*01:02
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed will give You Your desired output:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\{1,\}[0-9]*\*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\):[0-9][0-9]/\1/g'
```

Test:

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Z]\{1,\}[0-9]*\*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\):[0-9][0-9]/\1/g' file.txt > niceoutput.txt
$ cat niceoutput.txt
    G05829  H05037  A   A*02:01  A*11:01
    G05829  H05037  DRA DRA*01:01    DRA*01:02
    G05829  H05037  DPB1    DPB1*04:01   DPB1*04:02
    G05829  H05037  DRB3    DRB3*01:01   DRB3*01:01
    G05829  H05037  B   B*08:01 B*44:02
    G05829  H05037  DRB1    DRB1*03:01   DRB1*04:01
    G15526  H12517  B   B*07:02 B*35:01
    G15526  H12517  DRB5    DRB5*01:01   DRB5*01:01
    G15526  H12517  DRA DRA*01:02    DRA*01:02
```

However in your question You are mentioning that part `:[0-9]` can be n times, but You do not have that test case in Your example, if that's true You will need to change sed into this:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\{1,\}[0-9]*\*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)\(:[0-9][0-9]\)*/\1/g'
```

Test2:

```
$ cat jose_testcase2.txt
DPB1*01:02:02 or DQB1*49:34:01:03
DXX*05:05

$ sed 's/\([A-Z]\{1,\}[0-9]*\*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)\(:[0-9][0-9]\)*/\1/g' jose_testcase2.txt
DPB1*01:02 or DQB1*49:34
DXX*05:05
```

Comment: This works as a charm! You saved my day! If you have some time, can you explain me more detailed how reg expression are defined? what dies exactly the \{1,} works? And how it understands that multiple 'n' can occur? Thank you very much

Comment: Glad that helped. First part of regexp matches the prefix ABC*01:23, \{1,\} is the same as extended + in regexp one or more times occurrences, by default sed does not work with extended regexp so that's why I use \{1,\}. In second part I group regexp \(:[0-9][0-9]\)* in brackets and use star * as 0-N times regex that's why it knows N times. In the end I am replacing by \1 only first part of regex.